# Waveform of a SR Latch

Tags: digital-logic, latch, waveform

I need some help confirming what my answer sheet is indicating regarding the output waveform.

So far, everything I have matches up with the answer sheet except the last peak from output 'U'. The SET signal is pulsed so shouldn't the output 'U' be HIGH until the RESET signal is pulsed? If so, then why does the answer sheet show it pulsed and then returns to LOW?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You talk about SET and RESET but there are no signals named SET and RESET, so what do you mean? Actually, your "answer sheet" doesn't look at all correct to me. Are you sure you are looking at the answer sheet for the right problem?

Comment: Yeah that's the right answer sheet, I double checked with others. You're right it is wrong afterall. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The input's three gates ensure that only 'S' or 'T' can be high at any one time.

If 'S' is taken high then 'V' should latch high. If 'T' is taken high then 'U' should latch high. That is to say, taking an input ('S' or 'T') high forces the opposite gate's output to latch high.

So, the 'U' & 'V' labels on the timing diagram should be swapped over with each other. But, ignoring this then the last pulse is not exhibiting the latching action that should occur, as you have noticed. Taking 'Q' low, forces 'S' & 'T' low but this shouldn't cause a change in either 'U' or 'V'.

Comment: Ah thanks a lot for the in-depth explanation. I appreaciate it!